# Why is this weighted least squares cost function a function of weights?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, least-squares

Here is a picture from my book regarding weighted least squares:

[image]

Totally lost here, so I extracted the main nested issues confusing me:

- First Question: I know that in any LSE we want to minimize the cost function. The cost function is a function of the variable, $x$. In WLSE, I (thought?) the weights were set before hand, and dont change. So my first question is, why has he made the cost function $g(w)$ here, a function of the weights $w$? Shouldn't it purely be a function of $x$? Thats the value we are minimizing over after all.
- Second question: He says that we allow negative weights, (again, I thought they were set before hand), and in doing so, we allow "the objective function to be unbounded from below". What does this mean? If it means that $g(w)$ can take on the value of $-\infty$, why is that a bad thing?
- Third question: Probably related to the second one, but why is it important that the domain of $g(w)$ be $w$'s that make the $g(w) > -\infty$?

Comment: Could you post the same page of the same book for LSE ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You mean not the WLSE but the LSE one? I dont think there is one. [Here is the book](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf). This picture is from page 81, eg 3.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to broaden your definition of a "function" a bit.

When you fix a weight vector $w$ and solve the resulting weighted least squares problem, you  will obtain a particular value of the cost function $\inf_x \sum_i w_i(a_i^Tx-b_i)^2$. Let's call that value $g$. Sure, you'll also get a vector $x$ out of it, but just ignore it for now. Now, if you choose a different value of $w$, you will get a different value of $g$. A third value of $w$, a third value of $g$. And so on, and so forth.

If you want to, you could consider assembling an uncountably infinite list of all possible weight vectors $w$ and their associated values $g$. *What is a function but a compact mathematical representation of such a list*? Let us *define* the function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ in this way: to compute $g(w)$, fix the value of $w$, solve the weighted least squares problem, and return the resulting value of the cost.

That's exactly what is happening here. The particular value of $x$ you may get for any such $w$ is now irrelevant; the *focus* is on the weight vector $w$ and the cost $g(w)$ that it obtains.

Second question: When they say that they "allow the objective function to be unbounded below" they simply mean that, for some values of $w$ with negative entries, $\inf_x w_i(a_i^Tx-b_i)=-\infty$. Of course, you lose the "least squares" interpretation when you have negative weights, but as a purely mathematical construct, there's nothing wrong with doing that. There is nothing inherently bad about allowing a function to obtain the value $-\infty$, as long as you define things properly. And this book (Convex Optimization by Boyd & Vandenberghe) introduces the notion of extended-valued functions earlier.

Third question: it is *by definition* that the domain of an extended-valued function is the set of points for which the function is finite. Why is that important? Remember, infinity is not an actual number: it's a concept, a construct. In this context, it is best thought of as a placeholder: $g(w)=-\infty$ effectively means "the function is not well defined at this point."

Comment: I dont know. Im being thrown off by what appear to be contradictory statements in the example. In the highlighted line here, he says we have to minimize the objective function. Yes, agreed. Then in the same vein he says the $g(w)$ is an 'optimal' cost function, which is actually concave so we have to maximize it. Im not sure what the point here is anymore. What does he want to do?

Comment: I dont know what he is trying to do. Is he trying to _minimize_ the WLS objective function problem with fixed weights $w$ and variable $x$? Or is he trying to _maximize_ a 'new' cost function of fixed $x$ and variable $w$, that just to happens to be structured like a WLS problem? If the latter is true, then what does this have anything to do with weighted least squares where we always minimize the objective? I dont understand the overarching goal here.

Comment: The purpose of $g(w)$ is to capture how the cost value changes as $w$ is varied. That's it. Forget the weighted least squares problem completely, and just focus on that: $g$ is a function of $w$. 

Now, once you have that settled, you can ask: "how do I compute the value of $g(w)$ for a given value of $w$"? And the answer is: "by solving a weighted least squares problem where those are the weights."

Comment: Consider the following scalar function $g(w) = \inf_x x^2 + w x.$ This is a function of $w$; the purpose of $x$ is simply to *help you compute* $g(w)$. In this case, we can solve this one analytically, eliminating the need for $x$ altogether; $g(w)=-w^2/4$. This is *exactly the same function*, described in a different way. Both descriptions are entirely valid; one just uses a "helper" variable $x$. That's all $x$ is in the above function, too: a helper, to help you compute $g(w)$.

Comment: In fact: suppose the values of $w$ are all positive, and the vectors $a_i$ are linearly independent. Then
$$g(w) = b^T(W-WA^T(A^TWA)^{-1}A^TW)b$$where we have defined $W=\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n)$, and collected the vectors $a_i$ into the columns of $A$. The point is: $g$ is *just* a function of $w$; $x$ is irrelevant, except to help you compute the function.

Comment: Ok, I think that clears it up some Michael, thanks... It is still ruminating in my head for why we would ever need to do this, but I get the idea. So, I have to ask, do we ever have a problem put towards us in this fashion? That is, we want to maximize $g(w)$ as a function of $w$, and computing $g(w)$ for any $w$ involves solving a WLS problem. Ok... fair enough, can you give some examples of when/why this would ever come up in the real world? I think an application of this method would help me concretize it for me. That said, I believe I finally do see what is meant here thanks to you.

Comment: Oh I have no idea if something *precisely* like this comes up in practice. That's not the point, it's a contrived example to illustrate a specific concept. But in general, *minimax* problems are *extremely* common, as is the general concept of defining a function in terms of the solution to an optimization problem.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand completely: We have a function $g(w)$ that is a function of $w$. To compute a particular value for $g(w)$ at a particular $w$, _we just happen to need to_ solve a WLS problem, that just happens to also spit out an $x$. (The $inf_x$ is just a way of saying "pick the $x$ that minimizes this WLS problem, for your fixed $w$, or in other words, "solve the WLS problem)). We realize that since $g(w)$ is just made of $inf_x$ across a family of affine functions indexed by $x$, this makes it a concave function that can only be maximized. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Almost exactly right, except for this: "...that can only be maximized". Nothing prevents you from *trying* to minimize a concave function; sometimes you might even succeed. :-) But for a model to satisfy the definition of a *convex optimization problem*, yes, you must either maximize a concave function or minimize a convex function. And convexity does have practical implications, like tractability.

Comment: You minimize my ignorance Michael. And I hope for my sake that it is a convex opt problem! Thank you so much again. I'm slowly getting there. Until next time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

$g\left(\omega\right)$ is not the cost function here. $g\left(\omega\right)$ is the infimal value of this special cost function depending on omega: $\sum_{i}\omega_{i}\left(a_{i}^{T}x-b_{i}\right)^{2}$.

This defines a mapping $g:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup\left\{-\infty\right\}$.

The set of all points where $g$ is not infinity, we call $dom\left(g\right)$, i.e. $dom\left(g\right)=\left\{\omega\in\mathbb{R}^{n}|g\left(\omega\right)\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$

I hope this helps. What it's actually useful for is hard to state, depends on what the book aims at. Most probably they will later chose a "proper" cost function $\sum_{i}\omega_{i}\left(a_{i}^{T}x-b_{i}\right)^{2}$ with $\omega\in dom\left(g\right)$ and minimize that one...

Comment: Max thanks for your answer, for further context [here is the book](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf). Go to page 81, example 3.9. This is an example of how infimums of affine functions are concave. Oh, another source of confusion - its is concave, then I can only maximize it... but I have never heard of maximizing a cost function! ><

Comment: Why not? People maximize cost functions all the time. What if my cost function is a measure of profit? Look up "utility functions" in Google. You will find lots of discussion about concave utility functions. Maximizing a cost function is the same as minimizing the *negative* of that same function; and if a function is concave, its negative is convex.

Comment: what exactly is the question now? im reading around but don't really know what i'm looking for :-)

Comment: Are you taking CVX101? Seems to me you might benefit from using the discussion forums for that course. I am sure a lot of people are wrestling with the same issues and might have insights that may be helpful.

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant Ah yes... good point, never thought of it that way. I took 'cost' too literally.

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant Yes I am taking the MOOC. I ask there as well but active users are very, very little. We cross link to answers here often though.

Comment: Well, even if you take "cost" literally: you could be maximizing your *adversary's* cost. In other words, the mathematical model could represent your attempt to thwart someone else's plans, and you want to maximize their cost of operations.

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant Yeah, my only exposure to cost functions before has been minimal, and always involved minimizing power somewhere. This is good because it wrests those notions and expands them. Let me analyze your answer.

Comment: you could also always maximize your local entropy by throwing all your cups on the floor or by mixing the parts of all the puzzles you have in one box